# How to update D3 Zoomable sunburst wheel view with updating json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sunburst-diagram, sunburnt

Here i am try to update json data and its D3 wheel view but i Don't know why its not update the D3 sunbrust and update the data

This is my code 
// in html body

```
//css code
        svg{
          width: 100% !important; 
          background:#ffffff;
        }

        .slice {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .slice .main-arc {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

        .slice .hidden-arc {
            fill: none;
        }

        .slice text {
            pointer-events: none;
            dominant-baseline: middle;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }
        #tooltip { background-color: white;
              padding: 3px 5px;
              border: 1px solid black;
              text-align: center;}
              div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 8px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: #0a2538;
  border: #0a2538 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
}

//D3 Script code for https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js
const initItems ={
 "name": "Core root",
 "id":3,
 "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "VM.HSN.5.A",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "eiusmod",
     "children": [
      {"name": "G.8.1", "id": 5},
      {"name": "G.8.2", "id": 4}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "F.8.0",
     "children": [
      {"name": "F.8.4", "id": 1},
      {"name": "F.8.5", "id":1}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "EE.8.5-CLX",
     "children": [
      {"name": "EE.8.5-CLX2", "id": 1}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "NS.8.2-CLX",
   "children": [
    {"name": "NS.8.2-CLX4", "id": 1},
    {"name": "NS.8.2-CLX5", "id": 1},
    {
     "name": "NS.8.0",
     "children": [
      {"name": "NS.8.2", "id": 1},
      {"name": "NS.8.3", "id": 1}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "NS.8.1-CLX1", "id":1},
    {"name": "NS.8.1-CLX2", "id": 1},
    {"name": "NS.8.1-CLX3", "id":1},
    {"name": "NS.8.1-CLX4", "id": 1},
    {"name": "NS.8.1-CLX5", "id": 1}
   ]
  }  

 ]
}

var newItems = {
    "name": "Second Root",
    "children": [{
        "name": "A2",
        "children": [{
            "name": "B4",
            "size": 40
        }, {
                "name": "B5",
                "size": 30
            }, {
                "name": "B6",
                "size": 10
            }]
    }, {
            "name": "A3",
            "children": [{
                "name": "B7",
                "size": 50
            }, {
                    "name": "B8",
                    "size": 15
                }

            ]
        }]
}

const width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight,
maxRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 20;

const formatNumber = d3.format(',d');

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
.clamp(true);

const y = d3.scaleSqrt() 
 .range([maxRadius*.1, maxRadius]);

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

const partition = d3.partition();

const arc = d3.arc()
.startAngle(d => x(d.x0))
.endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
.innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0)))
.outerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y1)));

const middleArcLine = d => {
const halfPi = Math.PI/2;
const angles = [x(d.x0) - halfPi, x(d.x1) - halfPi];
const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);

const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw
if (invertDirection) { angles.reverse(); }

const path = d3.path();
path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);
return path.toString();
};

const textFits = d => {
const CHAR_SPACE = 6;

const deltaAngle = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);
const perimeter = r * deltaAngle;

return d.data.name.length * CHAR_SPACE < perimeter;
};

const svg = d3.select('#vdata').append('svg')
.style('width', '100vw')
.style('height', '100vh')
.attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)
.on('click', () => focusOn()); // Reset zoom on canvas click

var updateChart = function (items) {  
  //  var root = items;
    console.log(items);
//d3.json('dummy4.json', (error, root) => {
///if (error) throw error;           
//start custom code   
 var root = d3.hierarchy(items, function(d) { return d.children })
    .sum( function(d) {       
                if(d.children) {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return 2
                }
        });
//end custom code 
//root = d3.hierarchy(root);
//var ad =root.sum(d => d.depth); 
//root.sum(d => d.id);


const slice = svg.selectAll('g.slice')
.data(partition(root).descendants());

slice.exit().remove();

const newSlice = slice.enter()
.append('g').attr('class', 'slice')
.on('click', d => {
  console.log(d.data.name);
d3.event.stopPropagation();
focusOn(d);
});

newSlice.append('title')
//.text(d => d.data.name + '\n' + d.data.id);
//.on("mouseover", mouseover);

newSlice.append('path')
.attr('class', 'main-arc')
.style('fill',colour)
//.style('fill', d => color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name))
//console.log(data.id)
 .on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
.attr('d', arc);

newSlice.append('path')
.attr('class', 'hidden-arc')
.attr('id', (_, i) => `hiddenArc${i}`)
.attr('d', middleArcLine);

const text = newSlice.append('text')
.attr('display', d => textFits(d) ? null : 'none');

// Add white contour
text.append('textPath')
.attr('startOffset','50%')
.attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}` )
.text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
  })
.style('fill', 'none')
.style('stroke', '#fff')
.style('stroke-width', 5)
.style('stroke-linejoin', 'round');

text.append('textPath')
.attr('startOffset','50%')
.attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}` )
.text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
  });

//}); 
}

// tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

function colour(d) {
  //if (d.id==5) {
    var colours;
    console.log(d.data.id);
    if(d.data.id==5)
    {
    // There is a maximum of two children!
     colours ='#b00';
  }else if(d.data.name=='Apps'){
         colours='#cc0001';
  }
    else{
   colours=color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name)
  }   // L*a*b* might be better here...
   // return d3.hsl((a.h + b.h) / 2, a.s * 1.2, a.l / 1.2);
  //}
  return colours;
}

function mouseover(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("cursor", "pointer") 
      var descript;
      if(d.data.description!=null)
      {
       descript= "<br/><br/>"+d.data.description;
      }else{
        descript='';
      }
      tooltip.html(d.data.name + descript)
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 0 + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 0 + "px");
}
function mouseOutArc(){
     d3.select(this).style("cursor", "default")
      tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
}
function focusOn(d = { x0: 0, x1: 1, y0: 0, y1: 1 }) {
// Reset to top-level if no data point specified

const transition = svg.transition()
.duration(750)
.tween('scale', () => {
const xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]),
yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]);
return t => { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)); };
});

transition.selectAll('path.main-arc')
.attrTween('d', d => () => arc(d));

transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc')
.attrTween('d', d => () => middleArcLine(d));

transition.selectAll('text')
.attrTween('display', d => () => textFits(d) ? null : 'none');

moveStackToFront(d);

//

function moveStackToFront(elD) {
svg.selectAll('.slice').filter(d => d === elD)

.each(function(d) {
this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
if (d.parent) { moveStackToFront(d.parent); }
})
}
 } 

 updateChart(initItems);
```

> I am trying to update json data and regenerate the D3 sunburst wheel but it not update.
>   On developer console it show the json data updated but it not update the text in wheel and not properly regenerate the D3 sunburst wheel.

Please help me out.!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please format your question properly. You can use toolbar for formatting. See preview area before post your question. Clear questions with all the necessary points would improves your chances of getting good answers

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works for me great..!

```
setTimeout(function () {d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove(); updateChart(newItems); }, 2000);
```